# Merge background color and placeholder image in one image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am building a scratch card experience where I have a background color and a transparent png on the top.
Beneath this, I have the actual image with the content of the scratch card.
I want to combine the background color and the transparent image as one uiimage so that when i scratch this, I am able to see the below content.

I have tried putting a background color to the actual image but when I scratch it, I cannot see the content. Instead the background color starts clearing the transparent image.

[image]

I have written the following code for clearing the area of the image after i touch it:

```
- (UIImage *)addTouches:(NSSet *)touches {
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.image.size.width * self.image.scale, self.image.size.height * self.image.scale);
    CGContextRef ctx = _imageContext;
    
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx,[UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx,[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0].CGColor);
    int tempFilled = _tilesFilled;
    
    // process touches
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        touchPoint = fromUItoQuartz(touchPoint, self.bounds.size);
        touchPoint = scalePoint(touchPoint, self.bounds.size, size);
        
        if(UITouchPhaseBegan == touch.phase){
            [self.touchPoints removeAllObjects];
            [self.touchPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:touchPoint]];
            [self.touchPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:touchPoint]];
            // on begin, we just draw ellipse
            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x - _radius, touchPoint.y - _radius, _radius*2, _radius*2);
            CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, rect);
            CGContextFillPath(ctx);
            static const FillTileWithPointFunc fillTileFunc = (FillTileWithPointFunc) [self methodForSelector:@selector(fillTileWithPoint:)];
            (*fillTileFunc)(self,@selector(fillTileWithPoint:),rect.origin);
        } else if (UITouchPhaseMoved == touch.phase) {
            [self.touchPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:touchPoint]];
            // then touch moved, we draw superior-width line
            CGContextSetStrokeColor(ctx, CGColorGetComponents([UIColor clearColor].CGColor));
            CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2 * _radius);
            //            CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, prevPoint.x, prevPoint.y);
            //            CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y);
            
            while(self.touchPoints.count > 3){
                CGPoint bezier[4];
                bezier[0] = ((NSValue*)self.touchPoints[1]).CGPointValue;
                bezier[3] = ((NSValue*)self.touchPoints[2]).CGPointValue;
                
                CGFloat k = 0.3;
                CGFloat len = sqrt(pow(bezier[3].x - bezier[0].x, 2) + pow(bezier[3].y - bezier[0].y, 2));
                bezier[1] = ((NSValue*)self.touchPoints[0]).CGPointValue;
                bezier[1] = [self normalizeVector:CGPointMake(bezier[0].x - bezier[1].x - (bezier[0].x - bezier[3].x), bezier[0].y - bezier[1].y - (bezier[0].y - bezier[3].y) )];
                bezier[1].x *= len * k;
                bezier[1].y *= len * k;
                bezier[1].x += bezier[0].x;
                bezier[1].y += bezier[0].y;
                
                bezier[2] = ((NSValue*)self.touchPoints[3]).CGPointValue;
                bezier[2] = [self normalizeVector:CGPointMake( (bezier[3].x - bezier[2].x)  - (bezier[3].x - bezier[0].x), (bezier[3].y - bezier[2].y)  - (bezier[3].y - bezier[0].y) )];
                bezier[2].x *= len * k;
                bezier[2].y *= len * k;
                bezier[2].x += bezier[3].x;
                bezier[2].y += bezier[3].y;
                
                CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, bezier[0].x, bezier[0].y);
                CGContextAddCurveToPoint(ctx, bezier[1].x, bezier[1].y, bezier[2].x, bezier[2].y, bezier[3].x, bezier[3].y);
                
                [self.touchPoints removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            }
            
            CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
            
            CGPoint prevPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
            prevPoint = fromUItoQuartz(prevPoint, self.bounds.size);
            prevPoint = scalePoint(prevPoint, self.bounds.size, size);
            
            static const FillTileWithTwoPointsFunc fillTileFunc = (FillTileWithTwoPointsFunc) [self methodForSelector:@selector(fillTileWithTwoPoints:end:)];
            (*fillTileFunc)(self,@selector(fillTileWithTwoPoints:end:),touchPoint, prevPoint);
        }
    }
    
    // was _tilesFilled changed?
    if(tempFilled != _tilesFilled) {
        [_delegate mdScratchImageView:self didChangeMaskingProgress:self.maskingProgress];
    }
    
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    return image;
}

/*
 * filling tile with one ellipse
 */
-(void)fillTileWithPoint:(CGPoint) point{
    size_t x,y;
    point.x = MAX( MIN(point.x, self.image.size.width - 1) , 0);
    point.y = MAX( MIN(point.y, self.image.size.height - 1), 0);
    x = point.x * self.maskedMatrix.max.x / self.image.size.width;
    y = point.y * self.maskedMatrix.max.y / self.image.size.height;
    char value = [self.maskedMatrix valueForCoordinates:x y:y];
    if (!value){
        [self.maskedMatrix setValue:1 forCoordinates:x y:y];
        _tilesFilled++;
    }
}

/*
 * filling tile with line
 */
-(void)fillTileWithTwoPoints:(CGPoint)begin end:(CGPoint)end{
    CGFloat incrementerForx,incrementerFory;
    static const FillTileWithPointFunc fillTileFunc = (FillTileWithPointFunc) [self methodForSelector:@selector(fillTileWithPoint:)];
    
    /* incrementers - about size of a tile */
    incrementerForx = (begin.x < end.x ? 1 : -1) * self.image.size.width / _tilesX;
    incrementerFory = (begin.y < end.y ? 1 : -1) * self.image.size.height / _tilesY;
    
    // iterate on points between begin and end
    CGPoint i = begin;
    while(i.x <= MAX(begin.x, end.x) && i.y <= MAX(begin.y, end.y) && i.x >= MIN(begin.x, end.x) && i.y >= MIN(begin.y, end.y)){
        (*fillTileFunc)(self,@selector(fillTileWithPoint:),i);
        i.x += incrementerForx;
        i.y += incrementerFory;
    }
    (*fillTileFunc)(self,@selector(fillTileWithPoint:),end);
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you're building the actual image? If I'm understanding you correctly, your translucent image is getting cleared but not the background color of the image?

Comment: Do you want to start with a solid-color rectangle, and "reveal" the image? Or, do you want to start with an image, and "reveal a different image"?

Comment: @SeaSpell UIImage *info_icon          = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scratchcard_placeholder"];
 UIImage *imageResize = [self scaleImage:info_icon toSize:viewSize];
_imageScratched = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageResize]; _imageScratched.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

Comment: @DonMag I want to start revealing the image wherever the user places his finger on the card. So, ideally that image and background color should be considered as one.

Comment: Ok.. where are you filling and stroking? and what does this do [self.maskedMatrix setValue:1 forCoordinates:x y:y];

Comment: @AashnaNarula - ok, still not quite clear... Do you want to start with the image you've shown, but with a **solid dark green circle** ... and then "scratch off the dark green" to reveal the gift-box?

Comment: A few years ago I made a drawing app for kids that does what you want. In this case, you need two ways, the one that will be revealed is underneath and, on top of it, a colorized view that will be painted transparent when you swipe your finger. this example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXCk7d9R1V8

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is use a Layer Mask.

When masking a layer, from Apple's docs:

> The layer’s alpha channel determines how much of the layer’s content and background shows through. Fully or partially opaque pixels allow the underlying content to show through, but fully transparent pixels block that content.

So, you'd want to use a path to mask your dark circle.

However, to get the "scratch off" effect, you would need to draw the path with a Clear stroke... which you cannot accomplish with a `CAShapeLayer`.

So, we'll use a custom `CALayer` subclass.

**MyShapeLayer.h**

```
//
//  MyShapeLayer.h
//

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface MyShapeLayer : CALayer

@property(nonatomic) CGPathRef path;

@end
```

**MyShapeLayer.m**

```
//
//  MyShapeLayer.m
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyShapeLayer.h"

@implementation MyShapeLayer

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)inContext {
    // fill entire layer with solid color
    CGContextSetGrayFillColor(inContext, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(inContext, self.bounds);
    
    // we want to "clear" the stroke
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(inContext, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
    // any color will work, as the mask uses the alpha value
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(inContext, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    // adjust drawing-line-width as desired
    CGContextSetLineWidth(inContext, 60.0);

    CGContextSetLineCap(inContext, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(inContext, kCGLineJoinRound);
    CGContextAddPath(inContext, self.path);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(inContext, kCGBlendModeSourceIn);
    CGContextDrawPath(inContext, kCGPathFillStroke);
}

@end
```

Now we can create a `UIView` subclass to draw a filled-circle path on a `CAShapeLayer` and mask it with our `MyShapeLayer`.

**ScratchOffView.h**

```
//
//  ScratchOffView.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ScratchOffView : UIView

@property (assign, readwrite) CGFloat expandedBounds;

@end
```

**ScratchOffView.m**

```
//
//  ScratchOffView.m
//

#import "ScratchOffView.h"

#import "MyShapeLayer.h"

@interface ScratchOffView()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIBezierPath *maskPath;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyShapeLayer *maskLayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CAShapeLayer *scratchOffShapeLayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CALayer *scratchOffLayer;

@end

@implementation ScratchOffView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)commonInit {
    
    _maskPath = [UIBezierPath new];
    _maskLayer = [MyShapeLayer new];
    _scratchOffLayer = [CALayer new];
    _scratchOffShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer new];
    
    // Important, otherwise you will get a black rectangle
    _maskLayer.opaque = NO;

    // add the layer holding the shape to "Scratch Off"
    [self.layer addSublayer:_scratchOffShapeLayer];
    
    UIColor *c = [UIColor colorWithRed:50.0 / 255.0 green:150.0 / 255.0 blue:140.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [_scratchOffShapeLayer setFillColor:c.CGColor];
    
    // set the mask layer
    [_scratchOffShapeLayer setMask:_maskLayer];
    
    // default 0.0 == no expanded bounds for touch
    _expandedBounds = 0.0;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [_maskLayer setFrame:[self bounds]];
    [_scratchOffShapeLayer setFrame:[self bounds]];
    
    UIBezierPath *b = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:[self bounds]];
    [_scratchOffShapeLayer setPath:b.CGPath];
    
    // triggers drawInContext
    [_maskLayer setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    [_maskPath moveToPoint:currentPoint];
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    // add line to our maskPath
    [_maskPath addLineToPoint:currentPoint];
    // update the mask layer path
    [_maskLayer setPath:_maskPath.CGPath];
    // triggers drawInContext
    [_maskLayer setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // accept touch if within expanded bounds
    //  setting _expandedBounds to a Positive number allows the
    //  touches to start outside the frame
    CGRect r = CGRectInset([self bounds], -_expandedBounds, -_expandedBounds);
    return CGRectContainsPoint(r, point);
}

@end
```

Note that we've added a property: `expandedBounds`. Since the touches will only register if they *begin* on this view, we can (virtually) expand the bounds of the view so the user can touch and "drag into the circle."

Here is a complete example implementation. To try and match your question, I use this image (`420 x 460 pixels`) as the "background" image:

[image]

and this image (`284 x 284 pixels`) as the "image to reveal under the scratch-off circle" (the transparent area is the size we want the circle to be):

[image]

**ScratchOffTestViewController.h**

```
//
//  ScratchOffTestViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ScratchOffTestViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

**ScratchOffTestViewController.m**

```
//
//  ScratchOffTestViewController.m
//

#import "ScratchOffTestViewController.h"
#import "ScratchOffView.h"

@interface ScratchOffTestViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) ScratchOffView *scratchOffView;

@end

@implementation ScratchOffTestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    
    // create the Scratch Off View
    _scratchOffView = [ScratchOffView new];
    
    // load background and giftBox image
    UIImage *bkgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage"];
    UIImage *giftBoxImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"giftBox"];
    if (!bkgImage || !giftBoxImage) {
        NSLog(@"Could not load images!!!");
        return;
    }
    
    UIImageView *bkgImageView = [UIImageView new];
    UIImageView *giftImageView = [UIImageView new];
    
    bkgImageView.image = bkgImage;
    giftImageView.image = giftBoxImage;
    
    bkgImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    giftImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _scratchOffView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:bkgImageView];
    [self.view addSubview:giftImageView];
    [self.view addSubview:_scratchOffView];
    
    UILayoutGuide *g = [self.view safeAreaLayoutGuide];
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        
        // constrain background image view to background image size
        [bkgImageView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:bkgImage.size.width],
        [bkgImageView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:bkgImage.size.height],
        // centered
        [bkgImageView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.centerXAnchor],
        [bkgImageView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.centerYAnchor],

        // constrain giftBox image view to giftBox image size
        [giftImageView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:giftBoxImage.size.width],
        [giftImageView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:giftBoxImage.size.height],
        // centered horizontally, and a little above vertically
        [giftImageView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:bkgImageView.centerXAnchor],
        [giftImageView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:bkgImageView.centerYAnchor],
        
        // constrain Scratch Off View to giftImageView
        [_scratchOffView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:giftImageView.widthAnchor],
        [_scratchOffView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:giftImageView.widthAnchor],
        [_scratchOffView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:giftImageView.centerXAnchor],
        [_scratchOffView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:giftImageView.centerYAnchor],
        
    ]];
    
    // expand the touch bounds of the Scratch Off View by 80-pts
    _scratchOffView.expandedBounds = 80.0;
    
    return;

}

@end
```

On start, we see this:

[image]

and after touch-drag a bit on the circle, we see this:

[image]

If we continue dragging our touch around, the dark-green circle will eventually be completely gone -- we will have "scratched it off."